# Non linear fit with R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I try to obtain the first three coefficients for [Cauchy's dispersion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_equation) for Silicon. Using a csv containing the refractive index for some wavelengths (that you can find [here](https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=Si&page=Aspnes)), I try to fit the following model :

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(modelr)
library(broom)
library(splines)

# CSV parsing
RefractiveIndexINFO <- read_csv("./silicon-index.csv")

# Cleaning the output of the csv-parsing
indlong = tibble(RefractiveIndexINFO$`Wavelength. µm`,RefractiveIndexINFO$n)
names(indlong) = c('w','n')

# Remove some wavelengths that might not fit
indlong_non_uv = indlong %>% filter(indlong$w >= 0.4)

# Renaming variables
w = indlong_non_uv$w
n = indlong_non_uv$n

# Creating the non linear model
model = nls(n ~ a + b*ns(w,-2) + c*ns(w,-4), data = indlong_non_uv)

# Gathering informations on the fitted model
cor(indlong_non_uv$n,predict(model))
tidy(model)
```

Which gives the following error :

```
Error in c * ns(w, -4) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

How can I circumvent this situation and get the three coefficients (a,b,c) in a row ?

Obviously, using `model = nls(n ~ a + b*ns(w,-2), data = indlong_non_uv)` does not give an error.

Comment: In addition, explain what `-2` and `-4` (inside `ns`) should be. Degrees of freedom? Knots ? Or ?

Comment: The data file sure contains multiple datasets but the script do take care of retrieving only the relevant ones at `indlong = tibble(RefractiveIndexINFO$Wavelength. µm,RefractiveIndexINFO$n)`.
The `-2` and the `-4` are supposed to represent the respective power for the wavelengths, as explained in the first link. Sorry for the imprecision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(modelr)
library(broom)
library(splines)

# CSV parsing
RefractiveIndexINFO <- read_csv("aspnes.csv")
RefractiveIndexINFO <- RefractiveIndexINFO[1:46,]
RefractiveIndexINFO <- as.data.frame(apply(RefractiveIndexINFO,2,as.numeric))
names(RefractiveIndexINFO) <- c('w','n')

indlong_non_uv = RefractiveIndexINFO %>% filter(RefractiveIndexINFO$w >= 0.4)

# Creating the nonlinear model
model <- nls(n ~ a + b*w^(-2) + c*w^(-4), data = indlong_non_uv,
   start=list(a=1, b=1, c=1))

# Gathering informations on the fitted model
cor(indlong_non_uv$n,predict(model))
# [1] 0.9991006

tidy(model)
#   term    estimate   std.error statistic      p.value
# 1    a  3.65925186 0.039368851 92.947896 9.686805e-20
# 2    b -0.04981151 0.024099580 -2.066904 5.926046e-02
# 3    c  0.05282668 0.003306895 15.974707 6.334197e-10
```

Alternatively, you can use linear regression:

```
model2 <- lm(n ~ I(w^(-2)) + I(w^(-4)), data = indlong_non_uv)
summary(model2)

# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  3.659252   0.039369  92.948  < 2e-16 ***
# I(w^(-2))   -0.049812   0.024100  -2.067   0.0593 .  
# I(w^(-4))    0.052827   0.003307  15.975 6.33e-10 ***
```

Comment: Your proposition seems to give the expected answer. However, two questions raise :

* Is there any reason you are using `as.data.frame(apply(RefractiveIndexINFO,2,as.numeric))` instead of my `tibble(RefractiveIndexINFO$`Wavelength. µm`,RefractiveIndexINFO$n)` ?

* What is the main difference between the two ?

Comment: @SirC Please, check the columns of your `RefractiveIndexINFO`. They are characters or factors. In addition, from the help of `tibble`: tibble() is a trimmed down version of data.frame() that: Never coerces inputs (i.e. strings stay as strings!). Hence, your `indlong` is not numeric.

Comment: Okay thank you !
I realize that my second question is not precise : "What is the main difference between the two **answers** you gave ?"

Comment: Sure !
"Do you mean between nls and lm ? " : Yes that's my question.

Comment: If you consider the two covariates `x1=w^(-2)` and `x2=w^(-4)`,  your model is linear and is given by `y = a + b x1 + c x2`. Hence, it can be estimated by a simple linear regression. This is the reason why `nls` and `lm` give the same result.